# How to use int() on an entry value in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to create a GUI that converts a Hexadecimal Value to decimal.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk

def calc(s):
    i = int(s, 16)
    Label(root, text= str(i), font=('Helvetica', 12)) 

root = Tk()
root.title("Hexadecimal Converter")
Label(root,
                        text ="Hexadecimal to Decimal",
                        fg = "white",
                        bg = "gray61",
                        font = "Fixedsys 20 bold").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Finish', width=25, command=root.destroy)


root.geometry("375x200")

instructions = Label(root, text="Type in a hexadecimal value", font=('Helvetica', 12))
instructions.pack()

e = Entry(root)
root.bind('<Return>', calc)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()


root.mainloop()
```

I intended for the entry box to take a value, which is then converted from base 16 and returned in a label. However, I keep getting the error message:

```
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

I'm only a beginner with python, so I tried changing it to

```
def calc(s):
    s = str(s)
    i = int(s, 16)
```

and kept the rest the same, but it doesn't work either.

Is there a way for me to change the code so that the entry value is converted?

Comment: The parameter being passed to ``calc()`` is the event that triggered the binding - which you aren't really interested in, since you know it was a press of the <Return> key.  It is not in any way connected to the contents of the Entry; how could it be?  You need to use ``e.get()`` where you now have ``s``.

Comment: By replacing "s" with "e.get()" the code is not working due to syntax errors inside the function brackets. Should I replace the whole line of code binding the function to the <Return> key? If so, what with?

Comment: I mean, replace ``s`` in the function where you actually try to use it - the instance in the parameter list can remain as is (or change it to something more meaningful like ``event``).  Also: you aren't calling ``.pack()`` on the Label you create in calc(), so it will never appear.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I also changed the "Finish" button as I realized that it wasn't called properly either.